# error while integrating blogengine.net 2.0 to a website

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, blogengine.net

I was integrating the blogengine 2.0.what i did is

1. created  folder inside my project called blogs.
2. copied all the files from the blogengine.net 2.0 (web).
3. made changes in the web.config and changed master page path.
   as per

> http://www.ajaymatharu.com/integrating-blogengine-into-an-existing-site/

4.while running the project it is showing the error in styles.

the screen shoot of the error is...[image]

screen shoot of the project solution explorer is.

[image]

web.config file...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for but I would go the sub-domain route and avoid all of these issues completely. Also makes it easier to maintain and upgrade. Every time there is a BE upgrade you potentially face similar issues by trying to integrate it into an existing site.

Here's one I did already: http://homenetdirect.com/

All I had to do was customize the blog CSS to match that of the parent site - you might even create a "complimentary" design...